# Moving files from one folder to another

Tags: vba, file, move

I need to move a file from one folder to another folder using VBA.

```
For m = 1 To fnum
    MsgBox " Please Select " & m & "files"
    ffiles(m) = Application.GetOpenFilename
Next m

If Dir(outputfolder) = "" Then
    fso.createfolder (outputfolder)
End If

fso.Movefile ffiles(m), outputfolder  " getting error at this place "
```

I am getting an error message.

```
Error message id "Runtime error 438 . Object doesnt support this property "
```

Comment: And that error message is... ?

Comment: Error message id "Runtime error 438 . Object doesnt support this property "

Comment: For starters, I don't see `fso` declared anywhere in that code.  Second of all, why create an array of `ffiles` and then only move the last file?

Comment: Above i  gave just part of the program I declared fso as object Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  I need to copy the files and  consolidated into one . So i am taking file name as  ffiles(m) in array . so that i can copy many files and consolidated as one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite way of doing it. Using the `SHFileOperation` API

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Long

Private Const FO_MOVE As Long = &H1
Private Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS As Long = &H100

Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAnyOperationsAborted As Long
    hNameMappings As Long
    lpszProgressTitle As Long
End Type

Sub Sample()
    Dim fileToOpen As Variant
    Dim outputfolder As String
    Dim i As Long

    outputfolder = "C:\Temp\"

    fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(fileToOpen) Then
        If Dir(outputfolder) = "" Then MkDir outputfolder

        For i = LBound(fileToOpen) To UBound(fileToOpen)
            Call VBCopyFolder(fileToOpen(i), outputfolder)
        Next i
    Else
          MsgBox "No files were selected."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub VBCopyFolder(ByRef strSource, ByRef strTarget As String)
    Dim op As SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    With op
        .wFunc = FO_MOVE
        .pTo = strTarget
        .pFrom = strSource
        .fFlags = FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS
    End With
    '~~> Perform operation
    SHFileOperation op
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We can move files from one folder to another automatically using script 
https://seleniumautomations.blogspot.com/2020/05/less-than-5-sec-to-clean-and-organise.html?view=magazine

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)